# opencv background subtraction

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using background subtraction and I'm using python to do this but when I use the code it just seams to give me a black and white feed of what the camera is seeing. To my knowledge if nothing in front of the camera moves everything should go black, however this is a image of what I am getting.

Screenshot of problem:

[image]

This is the code that I am using.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Try leaving the pc for a few seconds after the program starts, so the background model is initialized correctly. 2) Are you sure you're running the **this** code? Seems like a threshold to me, not a background subtraction.

Comment: I tried leaving it running for a while but it made no difference. from what I can see it is just a variation on the mog2 that is on the opencv website (http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html#gsc.tab=0). I'm new to image recension so sorry if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Yes, your code seems correct. Could you please try with MOG2 and see if results are somehow different?

Comment: I just get a white screen when i move in the picture nothing happens

Comment: I can't tell... I can't test Python code, but the equivalent C++ code works perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible that my camera is causing the problem? i downloaded a example that had a video attached...when I ran the code with the video it worked but when I changed it to my camera I had the same problem as before.

Comment: Yes, it could be. how many channels has your `frame`?

Comment: Ok so I kind of have it working. When I record a video and pass it into the program it works like it should (actually it works very well). So it seams the problem is when I take it from a live feed. This is good as I can just record the video to get the next part of my project done..thanks so much for all of your help.

Comment: I should have replied to this ages ago. The problem was with the first image captured with the camera on setup. by adding a delay and recapturing the background image it solved the issue. I actually added a timer so the background image would update every 30 seconds

Answer (score 12):

First of all, you should perform background subtraction to grayscale images. What you, basically, should do is saving a frame as reference in the first place, then subtract it from following frames.

You would like to apply some kind of blurring beforehand, and a dilation operation afterward to reduce noise.

This is the most basic background subtraction operation you can do with basic algebra. What you need is a subtraction and a couple of morphological operation.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, first = cap.read()

# Save the first image as reference
first_gray = cv2.cvtColor(first, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
first_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(first_gray, (21, 21), 0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)

    # In each iteration, calculate absolute difference between current frame and reference frame
    difference = cv2.absdiff(gray, first_gray)

    # Apply thresholding to eliminate noise
    thresh = cv2.threshold(difference, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)

    cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key is pressed, break from the lop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What do you think `BackgroundSubtractorMOG` is?

Comment: @Miki BackgroundSubtractorMOG is high level background subtraction operation implemented in OpenCV. One should understand the idea of background subtraction completely in order to proceed advanced implementations like BackgroundSubtractorMOG. We should properly explain very basics of concepts like background subtraction to people who ask such questions, instead of throwing high-level functions at them.

Comment: Or we should teach them how to properly use library functions instead of reinventing the wheel. My concern is, however, that this doesn't answer the question, as you didn't point out what's the error in the code and provide a solution to that.

Comment: @Miki then you got a bunch of people who try to use libraries like jquery to perform basic operations like setting html (sorry for js example). This is not reinventing the wheel and I am not promoting it. It is teaching them the working logic of the wheel.

Comment: This is not the place for this discussion, and I won't go any further. My point is that this, while a valuable tutorial, is not answering the question.

Comment: @Miki question could be paraphrased as "How can I perform background subtraction using OpenCV". The person who asked the original question most probably tried the first example he stumbled upon on the internet, couldn't figured it out and posted it here. This answers the question, no matter you like it or not.

Comment: it works but I got 'missing picture in access unit' error after a while

Answer (score 1):

The Camera wasn't correctly capturing the first frame. It was just capturing a black image. To get around this problem I dumped the first frame, added a sleep, and then recaptured.